# How to hide a form from the main form

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I have been tweaking my program all day and I am having a problem hiding a form which will pop up saying "Please wait"

For example:

```
    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2 wait = new form2();
        pw.Show();
    }
    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2 wait = new form2();
        pw.Hide();
    }
```

This will not work, although I am sure this isn't news to the casual C# programmer. Is there a simple way to do what I am attempting? I have tried searching online and I did find something although I wasn't 100% sure what they were trying to do. I was going to find an example to show you but I closed page - Typical. However I think they were trying to overide the show and give you control over the .show with a bool?

Comment: So the problem is just hiding `pw`?

Comment: Yeah I cannot seem to hide it at all - No matter what I try.

Comment: Are you setting `pw` to another form somewhere else in code?  I've got a sample app setup with two buttons each with your actions listed above... my pw Hides and Shows just fine.

Comment: Maybe you can add some more code, showing how pw is declared and how the new form is assigned to pw?

Comment: whats this pw?? this problem dont seem to be big to me, share pw mystery first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code isn't working as you expect it to because the `form2` inside of `button12_Click` is different from the `form2` inside of `button13_click`.  Notice that you are using the `new` keyword twice.  So in `button13_click`, you are creating a new `form2`, and then hiding it, even though you haven't even shown it yet!

Instead you can create a single `form2` instance to share between your two methods:

```
//define this code outside both of the methods below
form2 _waitForm = new form2();

private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _waitForm.Show();
}
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this will hide the same form2 that was shown in button12_Click
    _waitForm.Hide();
}
```